# Windows 10 - Hybrid sleep and SSD

Tags: windows-10, ssd, sleep, shutdown

I recently had a problem with my desktop PC. I had Windows 10 installed on my HDD (along with Linux), and bought a SSD. I then moved my Windows 10 partition to my new SSD (had to sort out some boot problems because UEFI and stuff, but eventually got it to work).

Everything seemed to work fine, but when I tried to shutdown, it logged me out and took me to the login screen. I tried restart and it worked fine. Then I tried sleep, and it locked my session and turned the display off, but didn't sleep.

I searched the internet and tried a lot of suggestions that didn't work: checking powercfg for stuff preventing sleep, disabling fast startup, checking for driver and windows updates, ethernet wake up, multimedia sharing preventing sleep, and probably some more stuff I don't remember right now.

What finally solved it: disabling "hybrid sleep". Now both sleep and shutdown work fine.

But I wanted to understand: Why this fixed it? Why hybrid sleep interferes with shutdown? And why this happened with the SSD and didn't happen with the HDD (it was the exact same data, a cloned partition with all the same Windows configuration)?

I'm a computer scientist and programmer, so deep technical explanations are fine, and even desired (although I have very limited knowledge of Windows).

Comment: [Fast startup causes hibernation or shutdown to fail in Windows 10 or Windows 8.1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3211190/fast-startup-causes-hibernation-or-shutdown-to-fail-in-windows-10-wind)

Comment: I did try disabling fast startup, but it didn't solve it. I didn't expect it to solve this problem anyway, because my main issue was with sleep/suspend, not hibernate.